# Где находится frontend?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, frontend, thymeleaf

Сейчас делаю бэкенд часть на Java (spring). Там в качестве фронтенда используется таймлиф.

Когда мы поднимаем это на сервере, то наш фронт поднимается вместе с бэкенд частью тут же на сервере. Это учебный проект. Файлы фронта лежат в папке `template`.

Но ведь в реальном проекты фронтенд часть делается отдельно, другой группой разработчиков. И где тогда находится фронтенд? Он поднимается на другом сервере или вместе с бэкендом?

Comment: везде по разному, в зависимости от нагрузки на сервер

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как написали выше все зависит от проекта и от языка который был выбран для фронта. Например, я работал над некоторым проектом и у нас было 2 команды (фронт и бэк). Бэк представляет собой микросервисную архритектуру и написан на Java, фронт отдельным модулем на JS.
Бэк и фронт лежали внутри одного проекта (почитайте про модульность в Maven, Gradle).

Сервер это обычная машина, и на одном сервере вы можете развернуть сколько угодно приложений (если позволяют мощности).

Каждый микросервис бэка поднимается как отдельное приложение на сервере.
Фронт тоже представляет собой отдельное приложение и так же разворачивается на сервере (на одном с бэком или нет это уже решит девопс).

В вашем случае фронт генерится и управляется кодом из Java, поэтому у вас фронт и бэк совмещены в одно приложение.

Я знаю откуда ноги растут у этого вопроса, и на самом деле он не такой очевидный для новичков как кажется на первый взгляд.
Чтобы расставить все точки над "И" необходимо понять разницу между "фронтом" и "бэком".

Она заключается в том, что когда вы отправляете запрос к бэку вам возвращается какое-то сообщение (например если это под протоколом HTTP) в каком-то виде. Это может быть JSON, XML, текст и многое другое.

Когда вы отправляете запрос к фронту, на фронте есть какой-то шаблон страницы, фронт обращается к бэку за необходимыми данными для рендера этой страницы, и в результате вы получаете уже не JSON, XML или что-то еще, а текст, представляющий собой HTML разметку, а ваш браузер уже обрабатывает эту разметку и в итоге вы видите красивую страничку.